# How to get all ServerVariables in an ISAPI extension

Tags: c++, isapi

I have an old ISAPI extension that needs to pass forward server variables to another application. Currently the application pushes a number of fixed values explicitly to the backend application, but it would be much nicer to actually return all of them.

I know about ecb->GetServerVariable() which works just fine for individual server vars, but is there some way to iterate over all server variables somehow or grab them as a complete buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Call GetServerVariable with "ALL_HTTP" or "ALL_RAW"? Of course, then you'd have to handle pulling apart the header yourself.

Comment: ALL_HTTP doesn't get you all the headers unfortunately - only 'extra headers'. ALL_RAW - hmmm... not sure. I have to look at that but I don't think so.